# LinQ: join on nullable property with value null

Tags: vb.net, linq, join

I have a list of objects, with a property customerId which is a nullable System.Guid property.
I also have a list of id's of type System.Guid, I also added a Guid.Empty value to this list.

I try to do a join on both, but the objects with empty guids aren't returned.

```
Dim dos = (From d In documents Join c In allowedCustomers On c Equals If(d.CustomerGuid = Nothing, System.Guid.Empty, d.CustomerGuid) Select d).Skip(10 * (pageNr - 1)).Take(10).ToList
```

What is wrong? Is there another way to do this in a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `d.CustomerGuid = Nothing` but you have to use `d.CustomerGuid Is Nothing`.

Try this approach which uses the [VB.NET's null-coalescing operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513985.aspx).

```
Dim query = From doc In documents
            Join custID In allowedCustomers
            On If(doc.CustomerGuid, Guid.Empty) Equals custID
            Skip 10 * (pageNr - 1)
            Take 10
            Select doc
Dim docList = query.ToList()
```

Note that you can increase readability with multiple lines, also, VB.NET's query syntax is powerful than C#, so you can use `Skip` and `Take` in the query.